# Understand a proof that if $X$ is a Banach space, and $E$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then the quotient space $X/E$ is also a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Trying to understand a proof that if $X$ is a Banach space, and $E$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then the quotient space $X/E$ is also a Banach space.

Now they let $\{Y_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X/E$ and say that we need to only prove that a subsequence of $\{Y_n\}$ converges. They then pick a subsequence and state that they will just denote it lazily by $\{Y_n\}$ also, such that:

$$\|Y_{n+1} - Y_n\| \lt \frac{1}{2^n},\quad n=1,2,\cdots$$

- First question, why $\frac{1}{2^n}$?

Then they choose a $y_1\in Y_1$ and take $z_2\in Y_2-Y_1$ such that:

$$\|z_2\| \leq 2\|Y_2-Y_1\|$$

- What does it mean for $z_2\in Y_2-Y_1$? This must mean it lives in another coset of the quotient space?

Then he sets $y_2=z_2+y_1$ and obtains:

$$\|y_2-y_1\| \leq 2\|Y_2-Y_1\|$$

with $y_1\in Y_1$ and $y_2\in Y_2$ and says he continues the procedure and obtains the sequence $y_n\in Y_n$ such that:

$$\|y_{n+1} - y_n\| \leq 2\|Y_{n+1}-Y_n\|,\quad \forall n=1,2,\cdots$$

- I don't get it, so he takes some $z_3\in Y_{3}-Y_2$ such that $\|z_3\| \leq \|Y_3-Y_2\|$ then sets $y_3=z_3+y_2$ and obtains $\|y_3-y_2\| \leq \|Y_3-Y_2\|$ and so on. I don't even get why he can do this.

And says for all $m>n$ we have:

$$\|y_m-y_n\| = \| \sum_{k=n}^{n-1} (y_{k+1}-y_k)\| \leq  \sum_{k=n}^{n-1} \|(y_{k+1}-y_k)\|\leq 2\sum_{k=n}^{n-1} \|Y_{k+1}-Y_k\| \lt 4\frac1{2^n}$$

Which implies that $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence converges to some $y_0$ Set $Y_0=[y_0]$ we have:

$$\|y_n-Y_0\| = \| [y_n]-[y_0]\} = \|[y_n-y_0]\| \leq \|y_n-y_0\| \to 0,\rm{ as } n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

1) He takes $1/2^n$ so that, later on, he can control
$$
\|y_m - y_n\| \leq 2\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \|Y_{k+1} - Y_k\|
$$
so that $(y_n)$ may be Cauchy in $X$.

2) Note that $Y_2 - Y_1 \in X/E$ is a coset. Also,
$$
\|Y_2 - Y_1\| = \inf\{\|z\| : z\in Y_2 - Y_1\}
$$
Since $2\|Y_2-Y_1\| > \|Y_2-Y_1\|$, it cannot be a lower bound for this set, and hence such a $z_2$ exists.\3

3) Once again, he is using the fact that if $\alpha > 0$ is the infimum of a set, then $2\alpha > \alpha$, so $2\alpha$ is not a lower bound for the set. Hence there is an element of the set less that $2\alpha$.

Comment: So in regard to 1), he likely worked through the proof, wanted to seperate out $\|y_m-y_n\|$ and then he found a good choose for $\epsilon$ to base his $N(\epsilon)$ on to make his calculations neat?